# Using array map on returned value from promise

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I'm writing an async thunk in Redux to fetch Reddit posts, then map through the returned array to fetch each post's comments and add them to the new object.

```js
export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/fetchPosts", async ({ name, filter }) => {
    const data = await Reddit.getPosts(name, filter).then(async (val) => {
        const posts = await val.map(async (post) => {
            const comments = await Reddit.getComments(post.subreddit, post.id).then(val => {
                return val;
            });
    
            return { ...post, comments: comments };
        });
        
        return posts;
    });

    return data;
});
```

However, when the thunk is run in my app, an error occurs because the promises are still pending in the returned `data` object. How can I rectify this?

Comment: try Promise.all

Comment: If Reddit.getComments has some form of usage limits, you might find promise.all might get blocked, if so you might want to use `for of` instead.

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski That seems to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Promise.all()` on the returned data object ensured the array came back with all the fetched posts and their comments from Reddit as outlined.

```js
export const fetchPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/fetchPosts", async ({ name, filter }) => {
    // Fetching posts from Reddit
    const data = await Reddit.getPosts(name, filter).then(async (val) => {
        // Mapping through posts array
        const posts = await val.map(async (post) => {
            // Fetching comments for each post
            const comments = await Reddit.getComments(post.subreddit, post.id).then(val => {
                return val;
            });
    
            // Adding comments to each post object
            return { ...post, comments: comments };
        });
        
        return posts;
    });

    // Awaiting fulfillment of promises for each post in array
    const processed = Promise.all(data).then(val => {
        return val;
    });
    
    // Returning processed data with comments included
    return processed;
});
```